# What permissions and ownership should the 'static' folder have in production/

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

This is something I face everytime I deploy a Django app.. permissions.

Which group and user should own the static directory and what should the permissions look like?

I currently have:

```
drwxr-xr-x 7 www-data www-data  4096 Dec 11 05:29 static
```

My css files are getting a 403 response code when I visit my website so something must be wrong.

Comment: Have you installed whitenoise and included `whitenoise` middleware in your apps `MIDDLEWARE` list?

Comment: @AjayLingayat I haven't. I've never used it in my other apps

Comment: Okay So you have to add it then the static files will load into your project in production.

Answer (score 0):

Try following steps,

Install `whitenoise`.

```
pip install whitenoise
```

Add it into dependencies i.e `requirements.txt`.

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Add the `whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware` into `MIDDLEWARE` list in project settings.

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ....
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
]
```

I hope this works for you after deploying the project for production.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, after following these steps I still get 403 on my static files

Comment: So have you added the `STATIC_URL` & `STATIC_ROOT` in urls.py of your project?